# Getting unix time with wrong time/date on device android

Tags: android, time

Maybe smb asked similar question, but I didn't manage to find it at SO. I'm looking for working method of getting unix time from my device. BUT...I saw that system unix time depends on time/date preferences. So, I can get wrong data. I also know about such way:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
```

but it can return wrong number of milliseconds if I have wrong time/date on device. I also know about NTP servers which can give me unix time. Maybe we have some simple way of getting unix time which doesn't depend on user preferences. I thought that it can be smth like CPU time, but at the Internet CPU time is smth like  the amount of time for which a central processing unit (CPU) was used for processing instructions of a computer program or operating system so it is wrong for me. Maybe someone know about workable way? Thank you for your useful advice and help.

Answer (score 1):

This method returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC(coordinated universal time).

So it will return exactly the same value regardless of the locale of the device.

Comment: I know it :) I'm looking for independent source of millis for my app.